# 1 to 1 chat application is acting like a chat room

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a fragment where all the users using my app will be displayed. when the user clicks on one of the users he will be directed to a chat class where he will be able to chat. but the problem is whichever user he clicks on he's directed to the same chat room. for example if i text "stackoverflow" to person named "X" and open person named "Y" that "stackoverflow will be there also

my listview itemclick listener

```
 usersList.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            UserDetails.chatWith = al.get(position);
            Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), Chat.class);
            intent.putExtra("name",al.get(position));
            intent.putExtra("user_id",userid);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
    return rootView;
```

SendMessage method

```
private void sendMessage() {
 String messageText = messageArea.getText().toString();
 if (TextUtils.isEmpty(messageText)){
     Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Can't Send Blank Message",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    else {
     String message_sender_ref = "Messages/" + MessageSenderId + "/" + MessageRecieverId;
     String message_reciver_ref = "Messages/" + MessageRecieverId + "/" + MessageSenderId;

     DatabaseReference user_message_key = rootRef.child("Messages").child(MessageSenderId)
                                                 .child(MessageRecieverId).push();
     String message_push_id = user_message_key.getKey();

     Map messageTextBody = new HashMap<>();
     messageTextBody.put("message",messageText);
     messageTextBody.put("seen",false);
     messageTextBody.put("type","text");
     messageTextBody.put("time", ServerValue.TIMESTAMP);
     messageTextBody.put("from", MessageSenderId);


     Map messageBodyDetails = new HashMap();

     messageBodyDetails.put(message_sender_ref + "/" + message_push_id,messageTextBody);
     messageBodyDetails.put(message_reciver_ref + "/" + message_push_id,messageTextBody);

     rootRef.updateChildren(messageBodyDetails, new DatabaseReference.CompletionListener() {
         @Override
         public void onComplete(DatabaseError databaseError, DatabaseReference databaseReference) {
             if (databaseError != null){
                 Log.d("Chat_Log", databaseError.getMessage().toString());
             }
             messageArea.setText("");
         }
     });

 }
}
```

Where have i gone wrong? i'm kinda of thinking its on the item click listener because when i click on any item its directed to the same room. how do i solve this problem? please help

Comment: The code you've provided is not enough. Please read how to provide a [Minimal Complete Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Where do you get this `userId` used in `intent.putExtra("user_id",userid);`? How do you load it in the second Activity? Is it the sender's or the receiver's id?